# Diferencia entre un array y un vector

Tags: java

¿Cual es la diferencia entre en un array y un vector ?

Tengo una duda sobre donde es mejor alojar varios objetos, y no entiendo muy bien la diferencia entre vector y array, por lo que he leido en los dos se podria alojar un objeto excepto que en el array podria añadirlo o eliminarlo o modificarlo.

¿En que se diferencian?

Comment: ninguna.. array es vector en ingles... basicamente salvo que hables de alguna implementacion particular con objetos, son lo mismo...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Cuando te refieres a “vector” ¿te refieres a la clase Vector en java que implementa la interfaz List? ¿O te refieres a vector como concepto? Si te refieres a las diferencias de una lista y un array, la diferencia es que la lista tiene tamaño dinamico, es decir, puedes agregar cuantos elementos necesites y la lista crecerá, en cambio un arreglo siempre tiene un tamaño fijo y no puedes modificar su tamaño . En la práctica, la mayor parte del tiempo trabajarás con listas.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque a mi criterio personal no creo que aporte algo a la comunidad